# What is the expected lifespan of a Bambu Lab A1 mini?

Tags: cost, bambu-lab-a1-mini

I've seen a few sets of deprecation life numbers for 3D printers, but nothing for the Bambu Lab A1 mini. Is there an accepted deprecation life for the printer?

Ideally this would include a number of hours per month used in the calculations because I want to eventually work my way to a $/hr number which amortizes the cost of the printer over the hours it is expected to run.

Comment: With how new the printer is, it may be some time before any "hard" numbers come to light.

Comment: Maintain it like your car and it will last. Check for wear, repair parts, etc.

Comment: Just to *test* the machine to destruction, you'd have to run a printer a couple weeks or months in a test stand... if you want to estimate a price per hour, start with electricity and guesstimate a number of hours when you want your printer to be paid off. Typical for machinery is a number in the 3 to 4 digits.